# jQuery next returns -1

Tags: jquery, html

Hello I have some problem with jQuery next. For the begining I have markup looking like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
  <li class="active">...</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

In jquery I have collection of all 'ul' elements hold in variable eg. contElems. In this variable I find li with class active and then I try to get next elem. Code looks like this:

```
contElems.find('li.active').next();
```

It works when active li isn't last in ul but when it is last in ul next() returns -1. What is wrong with my code? And how can I make it work?:)

Comment: That is of course exactly how it works

Comment: `.next()` only looks at siblings of the selected element, not the collection that you derived the selected element from. You need to test that it's length is 0, and in that case, move to the next ul.

Comment: "Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector."

Comment: `next()` does not actually return `-1` in this situation, though. `index()` is probably involved somewhere.

Comment: do these li's contain the class "active", because in your example they do not...

Comment: @AndrewRhyne Yes they do... the last li in the first ul.

Comment: what version of jquery are you using? `next()` should not return `-1`... http://jsbin.com/itevat/1/

Comment: @user1785951 What output do you want when `li.active` is the last? What you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is:

```
contElems.find('li.active').siblings().first();
```

That way you make sure you get 1 sibling even if the matched `ul` is the last one...

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no next element after the `li.active`. If you're just trying to access `li.active` then use `contElems.find('li.active')`.

What behavior are you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

If it's the last one, then there is no `next()` one, so you get a falsy value. Personally, if I'd written `next()`, I'd have it return `null`, but apparently it was decided that a return value of `-1` means that there is no next element.

Comment: Where is -1 coming from? `.next()` returns a jQuery object that either contains elements or doesn't contain elements. either way, it's an array-like object, not -1...

Answer (score 0):

From [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/next/):

> Description: Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

There is no "immediately following sibling" of the last element.

You can try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/paska/G8nF3/1/):

```
function getNext(contElems) {
    var next = contElems.find('li.active').next();
    if (next != undefined && next != null && next != -1 && next.length > 0)
        return next;

    var list = contElems.find('li'),
        eq = list.index(contElems.find('li.active'));

    next = list.eq(eq + 1);     return next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.next()` finds the next sibling (same parent). If you want to find the `li` in the next `ul` (which is a cousin rather than a sibling), you can do it like this:

```
var el = contElems.find('li.active').next();
if (el.length == 0) {
    el = contElems.find('li.active').closest('ul').next().find('li:first');
}
if (el.length == 0) {
    alert("Last li is active!");
}
```